Expo go in browser
I'm using expo go in browser for building an App using React Native.
Whenever I want to import axios, I get problems like this :
components/Signup.js (0:1)
Unable to resolve module 'module://@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault.js'(Device)
Evaluating module://@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault.js
Evaluating module://axios.js
Evaluating module://components/Signup.js.js
Evaluating module://App.js.js
Loading module://App.js`

Does anyone know what causes this?

Does this answer solve your problem?
